# How to set custom rates, for throttling in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I'm using DRF for throtlling, according to the [document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#setting-the-throttling-policy) I can choose one of these options for my rate : 
second, minute, hour, or day.

But the problem is, that I want a custom rate, for example, 3 requests per 10 minutes.

Is it possible in DRF ?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#custom-throttles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by extending [`SimpleRateThrottle` or any other class that extends `SimpleRateThrottle` (`UserRateThrottle` etc.)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py).

Take a look at the [`parse_rate` method of `SimpleRateThrottle`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/ec1b14174f8717337fc4402c7cea43f647e2586e/rest_framework/throttling.py#L97):

> It takes request rate string as input and returns a two tuple of:
>   (allowed number of requests, period of time in seconds)

So if you write a class to override this parsing logic, you should be good to go.

For example:

```py
from pytimeparse.timeparse import timeparse

class ExtendedRateThrottle(throttling.UserRateThrottle):
    def parse_rate(self, rate):
        """
        Given the request rate string, return a two tuple of:
        <allowed number of requests>, <period of time in seconds>
        """
      if rate is None:
          return (None, None)
      num, period = rate.split('/')
      num_requests = int(num)
      duration = timeparse(period)
      return (num_requests, duration)
```

[Run this example](https://repl.it/@mehamasum/ExtendedRateThrottle) and see `3/10m` resolves to `(3, 600)`.

Now use this class as your `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES` or however you would use any other throttling class.

Comment: Thank you so much, although I haven't used your solution yet, it looks awesome.